# RapidJSON/C++: Create std::vector<?> from JSON array

Tags: c++, templates, generics, stdvector, rapidjson

I want to read a JSON document with [RapidJSON](https://rapidjson.org/). My JSON document contains a multi-dimensional matrix and has the following form:

```
{
  "shape": [1, 120, 42],
  "type": "float32",
  "data": [0.123, 0.234, ..., 0.345]
}
```

I would like to write a `ReadArray` function that can read the arrays with numbers (e.g., shape and data in this example) into a `std::vector`. The type of the vector should be int for the shape and appropriate (float/int) for the data.

What I have tried is:

```
template <typename ValueType>
void ReadArray(rapidjson::Value& jsonArray, std::vector<ValueType> output) {
    for (auto it = jsonTensor.Begin(); it != jsonTensor.End(); it++) {
        output.emplace_back(it->Get()); // error: No matching member function for call to 'Get'
    }
}
```

I will call this as follows:

```
std::string dataPath("/path/to/data.json"); // data.json content see above

std::ifstream dataInputStream(dataPath);
rapidjson::IStreamWrapper dataInputStreamWrapper(dataInputStream);
rapidjson::Document jsonTensor;
jsonTensor.ParseStream(dataInputStreamWrapper);

auto jsonShape = jsonTensor["shape"].GetArray();
std::vector<int64_t> shape;
ReadArray(jsonShape, shape);

auto jsonData = jsonTensor["data"].GetArray();
std::vector<float> data;
ReadArray(jsonData, data);
```

At the location where I try to get the value from the JSON array, I get the error "*No matching member function for call to 'Get'*" [1]. Using `rapidjson::GenericValue` instead of `rapidjson::Value` is also not working for the same reason. `rapidjson::GenericArray<false, ValueType>` instead raises "*No matching function for call to 'ReadTensor'*" in the location where I run `ReadArray` [2].

How could I solve this issue? How could I convert the `rapidjson::Value` to an array type or should I try something completely else here?

[1] Error message when using `Value`:

```
/home/user/test/main.cpp: In function ‘void ReadArray(rapidjson::Value&, std::vector<ValueType>)’:
/home/user/test/main.cpp:17:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >::Get()’
         output.emplace_back(it->Get());
                                     ^
In file included from /home/user/test/main.cpp:7:0:
/home/user/.local/include/rapidjson/document.h:1912:7: note: candidate: template<class T> T rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::Get() const [with T = T; Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>]
     T Get() const { return internal::TypeHelper<ValueType, T>::Get(*this); }
       ^
/home/user/.local/include/rapidjson/document.h:1912:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/user/test/main.cpp:17:37: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
         output.emplace_back(it->Get());
                                     ^
In file included from /home/user/test/main.cpp:7:0:
/home/user/.local/include/rapidjson/document.h:1915:7: note: candidate: template<class T> T rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::Get() [with T = T; Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>]
     T Get() { return internal::TypeHelper<ValueType, T>::Get(*this); }
       ^
/home/user/.local/include/rapidjson/document.h:1915:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/user/test/main.cpp:17:37: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T’
         output.emplace_back(it->Get());
                                     ^
```

[2] Error message when using `GenericArray`:

```
/home/user/test/main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/user/test/main.cpp:89:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘ReadArray(rapidjson::GenericArray<false, rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> > >&, std::vector<long int>&)’
     ReadArray(jsonShape, shape);
                               ^
/home/user/test/main.cpp:15:6: note: candidate: template<class ValueType> void ReadArray(rapidjson::GenericArray<false, ValueType>&, std::vector<ValueType>)
 void ReadArray(rapidjson::GenericArray<false, ValueType>& jsonTensor, std::vector<ValueType> output) {
      ^
/home/user/test/main.cpp:15:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/user/test/main.cpp:89:31: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘ValueType’ (‘rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> >’ and ‘long int’)
     ReadArray(jsonShape, shape);
                               ^
```

Comment: What is `jsonTensor`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I'll rectified my question. `jsonTensor` is the `rapidjson::Value` containing the JSON data example mentioned above: `{
  "shape": [1, 120, 42],
  "type": "float32",
  "data": [0.123, 0.234, ..., 0.345]
}`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `it->Get<ValueType>()`? Please post the whole multi-line error message, that should give hints.

Comment: Ok. I added the compilation errors. `it->Get<ValueType>()` also doesn't work: "Use 'template' keyword to treat 'Get' as a dependent template name"

Comment: `it->template Get<ValueType>()`

Comment: I see. I didn't knew that was valid syntax. However, in that case, the problem shifts to the call of `ReadArray`. I need to find a way to convert `rapidjson::Value` to `rapidjson::GenericArray`: `no matching function for call to ‘ReadArray(rapidjson::GenericArray<false, rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<> > >&, std::vector<long int>&)`

Comment: @273K Thanks, I've got it. `it->template Get<ValueType>()` directly made it work. If you post an answer, I'll accept it and delete my own answer. Otherwise, I'll accept my own answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @273K, I could get it to work as follows:

```
template <typename ValueType>
void ReadArray(rapidjson::Value jsonArray, std::vector<ValueType>& output) {
    for (auto it = jsonArray.Begin(); it != jsonArray.End(); it++) {
        auto value = it->template Get<ValueType>();
        output.emplace_back(value);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::ifstream dataInputStream(dataPath);
    rapidjson::IStreamWrapper dataInputStreamWrapper(dataInputStream);
    rapidjson::Document jsonTensor;
    jsonTensor.ParseStream(dataInputStreamWrapper);

    auto jsonShape = jsonTensor["shape"].GetArray();
    std::vector<int64_t> shape;
    ReadArray(jsonShape, shape);
}
```

The missing link was to use `it->template Get<ValueType>()` instead of `it->Get()`.